# Проверить наличие объекта Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как проверить наличие такого же объекта рядом? Допустим, с тем же тегом? 
Например, в Match3 игре, нужно проверить, находится ли рядом объект с тем же тегом, а если находится - проверить то же самое и для него? Видел в интернете варианты с массивами, и никто тегами не пользуется. Как это реализовать, если скрипт перебора навешан на каждый объект?

Comment: Надо, скорее, пересмотреть логику своей игры, а не пытаться реализоваться костыли невообразимыми способами, лишь бы сделать так как вы хотите, а не как правильно....Какой смысл вешать скрипт с проверкой на объект, которых сотнями может быть на сцене? Проще как раз таки иметь один менеджер, который будет иметь тот самый массив, коллекцию объектов с их типами и иметь логику сравнения их близостного расстояния между объектами и направлять, в результате вычислений, кого прикончить......А иметь кучу объектов с кучу ифами с кучей проверок и нарастанием костылей - неправильный путь.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Благодарю вас, т.е. единственный адекватный способ - внесение в массив и сверка по координатам? Или есть всё таки альтернатива, пусть не такая, которую я описал, но вообще, есть?

Comment: Ну в данном случае, как мне кажется, нет смысла как-то что-то усложнять. Как правило в таких простых играх, типа тетрис, арканойд или match3 и похожих все строится по одному сценарию: генерируется сетка из нулей и единиц (в случае простого арканойда) или от нуля до N .... где нули означают пустую ячейку, а другая цифра - один из типов блоков.... далее просто инстанциируются объекты исходя из этой сетки... ... дальше логика сводится к управлению этим массивом, а объекты просто появляются и исчезают в зависимости от сетки..им нет смысла что-то знать о ком-то рядом или вдалеке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**В общем ты просишь подсказать как делать костыльно.**

**Имей это ввиду.**

Но ответ есть.

Юзай Physics.Sphere что бы узнать все обьекты которые находятся на заданном растоянии вокруг заданного обьекта.
А потом перебирай коллайдеры которые оно словило и проверяй на что нужно эти обьекты. То ли на имя, то ли на тэг, то ли на любой другой параметр.